# Angular checkbox changeDetection

Tags: angular

I have a simple checkbox component:

```
ts: @Input() checked: boolean;

html: <input type="checkbox [checked]="checked" #input>
```

So far so good works as expected. It is a simple one way binding.

But after the user clicks on it I want a function to restore the original state (kinda cancel).

I tried some change detection to trigger the html content and get the original value but It doesn't work.

```
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: try two way binding `[(ngModel)]="checked"` instead of `[checked]="checked"`

Comment: You could do (as mentioned above) two way data binding for the check status and use one way data binding for setting the default value, so you could set, if there is no value for [default], the default status is false but you could set the [default]="true" to have it's status true by default. That's what I would do

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling function when the state is changed

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox (change)="checkChange($event)" [checked]="checked" #input>
```

**TS**

```
checkChange(event) { 
     console.log(event.checked);
}
```